# Getting an "expected: end of statement" error in VBA

Tags: sql, vba

I am building a login screen in Microsoft Access "username" is what is highlighted after I get the error code.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE * "username = '" + Me.txtUserName + "'"

    End With

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

    If rs.EOF Then
        IncorrectUserNameStyle
        Exit Sub
    End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a typo in the query (a `"` where it shouldn't be), it's marked below:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE * "username = '" + Me.txtUserName + "'"
                                   ^ end of string
                                 ^ probably a mistake
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not looking good, how about this:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '" + Me.txtUserName + "'"

    ' End With -- what's this?

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

    If rs.EOF Then
        'IncorrectUserNameStyle -- what's this?
        MsgBox("Username not found", 0)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' End If -- what's this?
End Sub
```